# Domino http 500 internal server error

Tags: java, xpages, lotus-domino

I have domino designer project contain forms,views and xpages ,I can run forms and views by preview in web browser but when I try that in xpages I get HTTP 500 Internal Server Error(  The website cannot display the page ) also I can preview xpages in other project but this project I can't

Comment: If you use a Designer Version 8.5, then this is a known bug. As soon as the database is in a Subfolder and not directly in Data- Directory, then this will happen after every change you do in an XPage or a custom control. 

You can either put the database directly in data- directory during development or update your designer to 9.0.1.

Comment: I have never seen an issue with preview and sub directories in 8.5 or any Designer version. Our courses always are in sub-directories and we always use local preview for demos, etc.

Comment: Does your project use any plug-ins like the Extension Library? If so, then you have to copy the files from the features directory of the plug-in to the features directory in C:\notes\data\domino\workspace\applications\eclipse (change C:\notes\data for your system). Do the same for the plugins directory.

Comment: Step 1: go to the application properties and select: display standard error messages. This will most likely give you a more detailed error. There are a few that still result in a 500, but that's a first step.  Let us know the new error message